# Vue3 Checkbox unit test fails as checked prop isn't set

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vitest

I'm trying to implement unit tests for my custom checkbox component! To implement I used composition API and the `v-model` directive. The code is straightforward:

```js
<template>
  <div class="checkbox-container">
    <input
      :id="props.id"
      v-model="checked"
      type="checkbox"
      :disabled="props.disabled" />
    <label :for="id">{{ props.label }}</label>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import {ref} from 'vue';
export interface CheckBoxProps {
  id: string;
  checked: boolean;
  disabled?: boolean;
  label: string;
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<CheckBoxProps>(), { disabled: false });

const checked = ref(props.checked)
</script>
```

And this is my test case:

```js
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Checkbox from '@/components/Checkbox.vue';

  test('changes checked prop when checkbox is clicked', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Checkbox, {
      props: {
        id: 'my-checkbox',
        checked: false,
        label: 'My Checkbox Label'
      }
    });

    const input = wrapper.find('input[type="checkbox"]');

    expect(wrapper.props().checked).toBe(false);

    await input.trigger('click');

    expect(wrapper.props().checked).toBe(true);

    await input.trigger('click');

    expect(wrapper.props().checked).toBe(false);
  });
```

However I'm having a problem to change the value of `checked` prop. It appears not to be changing, even after a click trigger. The test is falling with the following error:

```bash
AssertionError: expected false to be true // Object.is equality
 ❯ test/components/Checkbox.spec.ts:43:37
     41|     await input.trigger('click');
     42|
     43|     expect(wrapper.props().checked).toBe(true);
       |                                     ^
     44|
     45|     await input.trigger('click');

  - Expected   "true"
  + Received   "false"
```

I'm new to Vue so I tried to replicate what on Vue docs about `v-model`. In [this checkbox example](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#checkbox) they use only `v-model` and a `ref` variable... I had implemented in a wrong way?

Comment: you're checking the prop.checked value, which is always false in your example. You should check the checked ref value instead.

Comment: Indeed, I need to check the `ref`. Thanks for. your help!